# Configure XDM to accept remote logins

Tags: linux, xdmcp, xdm

How can I configure XDM server to accept remote X login and works as X server, which Configuration should be done on the clients if they want to connect to this X server?

Answer (score 3):

To allow XDM remote logins you can do following:

1. Edit file: `/etc/X11/xdm/Xaccess`

change(uncomment) line:

```
# *                       #any host can get a login window
```

to:

```
*                         #any host can get a login window
```

and change(uncomment):

```
# * CHOOSER BROADCAST #any indirect host can get a chooser
```

to:

```
* CHOOSER BROADCAST #any indirect host can get a chooser
```

2. Edit `/etc/X11/xdm/xdm-config`

change(comment) line:

```
DisplayManager.requestPort:    0
```

to:

```
!DisplayManager.requestPort:    0
```

3. Restart XDM

On client machine start the Xorg server like this (assuming that you have already X running on :0):

```
X :1 -query ip_address
```

This will bring XDM to your display at display :1 and now you can login and work on client machine as you are logged directly to the server and switch between local and remote X with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Fxx</kbd>.
For Windows clients (I have never tested.) you can check [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming).

As XDMCP is using the below ports and make sure these ports are open in firewall:

- XDMCP 177 UDP
- X11 protocol 6000-6005 TCP
- xfs: X font server 7100 TCP

Consider allowing remote XDMCP session for public addresses is not very secure. You can think using it through VPN or over SSH.

Different distributions might require additional files to be configured, for example in openSUSE 13.1 `/etc/sysconfig/displaymanager` following value should be set to YES:

```
DISPLAYMANAGER_REMOTE_ACCESS="yes"
```

Comment: Nice answer.  The `X :1 -query ip_address` is usually written in `/etc/X11/xdm/Xservers`.  Running `xfs` is usually a good idea, for performance reasons.  Also X11 protocol needs 10 extra TCP ports above 6000 for each server.  So you need 6000-6010 for `X :0`, 6011-6020 for `X :1` etc.  For security reasons, access to these ports should be allowed only from the local net.